# What is the meaning of u8R"delim(SomeTextInHere)delim" in C++?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

Right, here's something I've not seen before. The following snippet of code was found in the wild (though I'm paraphrasing since I don't have access to the original):

```
char str[] = u8R"delim(SomeTextInHere)delim";
```

Can anyone actually tell me what this means and what the equivalent would be in C?

Comment: If someone wrote that in the wild, they are crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent in C as of yet. This is a C++11 feature that combines two things.

The `u8` prefix means that the string will be encoded in UTF-8. The `R` prefix means that it is a raw string literal. Combining them means that the raw string will be UTF-8 encoded.

Raw strings are a way to get around all the escaping necessary for regular expressions and so forth. Normally, in a regex, you have to use a lot of "\" characters. But that's the C/C++ escape character, so in string literals, you have to use "\" instead. Raw string literals allow you to avoid that. In raw strings, there are no escape characters.

The way a raw string literal works is as follows. The `R` prefix is followed by `"` as usual. But the characters up to the first `(` character are all considered part of the delimiter of the raw string. So, if you start a raw string with `R"foo(`, the string will continue until the parser sees, `)foo"`.

This way, you can use `"`, `\`, and virtually any other characters, as long as you choose your delimiters will. The delimiter can be empty too, so `R"(some stuff)"` is equivalent to `"some stuff"`. It ends when it sees `)"`.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know how to translate it into C sir, but this is throwing almost all the new literals related stuff in one example.

```
u8: utf-8 string literal.
R: Raw string literal (no escape characters)
"delim(" ... ")delim": The prefix and suffix of the raw string literals. 
                       They are used as delimiters, and you can write your own.
```

Comment: My _father_ was called "sir", you can just call me pax :-)